# The equation to the sides of a triangle are $x-3y=0$, $4x+3y=5$ and $3x+y=5$. Prove that the line $3x-4y=0$ passes through the orthocentre

Tags: linear-algebra, triangles

The only line capable of being perpendicular to $3x-4y=0$ is $4x+3y=4$

The point opposite to this side is $\left( \frac 32, \frac 12 \right)$

Clearly, $3x-4y=0$ does not pass through this particular point, and hence it cannot pass through the orthocentre.

What’s wrong with my proof?

Answer (score 1):

Actually $4x+3y=k$ will be perpendicular to $3x-4y=0$ for *any* $k$.

The first and third lines $x-3y=0$ and $3x+y=5$ are perpendicular to each other and thus their intersection $(3/2,1/2)$ is the orthocenter of the triangle.  But this does not match $3x-4y=0$ so the claim as written is false.

Do not dismiss the possibility of a typographical error.  If the third line is $3x+y=\color{#0055ff}{0}$, putting the orthocenter at the origin, the proof works.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, but if we go by the values given here, the answer is wrong?

Comment: Your first part about the line perpendicular to $3x-4y=0$ having to be just $4x+3y=4$ is wrong as I state in the first sentence.  But your finding that $3x-4y\ne 0$ at the orthocenter is correct.

Comment: Oh no, I meant it is the only line perpendicular from the given set of lines

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

The altitude to the red line $y=\frac13x$ passing through $(2,-1)$ is:
$$y=-3x+5$$
The altitude to the blue line $y=-\frac43x+\frac53$ passing through $(1.5,0.5)$ is:
$$y=\frac34x-\frac58$$
The altitude to the green line $y=-3x+5$ passing through $(1,\frac13)$ is:
$$y=\frac13x$$
The three altitudes intersect at $(1.5,0.5)$.

Clearly, the line $3x-4y=0$ does not pass through this point. And it must be a typo in the source.